# Camera battery door

Tags: canon

Were you ever able to fix the door to your camera battery? I am having the same issue. I unfortunately dropped my camera and the door popped right off and flew off into the unknown abyss known as my kitchen. Please help!

Comment: Hi Anna! I'm guessing that you posted this because you previously posted it as an answer or comment on an existing question, and were told to submit it as a new question instead. That's great, but now we have no idea who "you" is or even what "the same issue" is. Could you link to that, please?

Comment: Also, what camera model is this?

Answer (score 1):

This part is removable in case you want to use a Battery Grip.

What you can do is:

- if you feel lucky - search the kitchen well,
- find a new door on the internet (aliexpress?),
- mount a battery grip instead - bonus: extra space for a 2nd battery,
- use a duct tape to close the hole (* if you think about this seriously, read also the --EDIT-- section below),
- or <strike>get used to the new look&feel of your camera</strike>... ;-)

--EDIT--

That suppose to be kind of a funny answer, but it got serious.

As @flolilolilo pointed out in the comment, the "duct tape" option itself wouldn't work, as there is a small hole (next to the battery compartment) where is located a micro switch detecting if the door were closed. There must be something put into the hole pushing the micro switch. That may be a small stripe of paper or similar thing attached to the body or tape closing the compartment. Just try not to drop anything inside the camera's body...

Because of the same reason, I am crossing out the point about getting used to the new look&feel, as it won't solve the problem.

Comment: If you `use a duct tape to close the hole`, depending on the camera, you will also need to create a solution for the pin that usually tells the camera that the battery door is shut - without that, e.g. most Canon cameras I know of won't turn on.